# Database creation on Linux with dbca: "command not found"

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle-10g

I have installed an Oracle on my machine. When I open a session with VNCServer and type `dbca`,  either as `root` or as `oracle`, I get these errors:

1. `-bash : -dbca : Command Not found`
2. `Xlib: connection to ":0.0" refused by server`
   `Xlib: No protocol specified`

What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: run this command as root user
[root@localhost]# xhost +
then switch to oracle user and try with dbca

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your first error ('dbca: command not found'):

- ensure ORACLE_HOME is set correctly
- ensure $ORACLE_HOME/bin is in your path
- run the command as oracle user

If the error persists, check the contents and permissions of $ORACLE_HOME/bin.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://youtu.be/ue7D6K9cFys)  amazing video explains how to solve the error step by step,

If you dont want to watch then follow the text below

1) "Command not found" indicates oracle instance is not running or you have not running the dbca command as oracle user
sol: follow @Frank Schmitt answer

2)The No protocol specified error indicates that "the user dont know how to launch UI application" and " user has no permission to lauch UI application" , in this case dbca is a GUI app.
sol: as a root run "xhost -" (without quotes)